# Combo Box in Access 2010 repeats options

Tags: ms-access, combobox

Here is an issue that I am facing. The entries in my combo box Branch_Name are repeating themselves,and I want them NOT to appear twice in the combo box. In the main table the entries in the Branch_Name column are repeated multiple times, but I do not want them to be relfected multiple times in the combo box, which I use in a Data Entry form.

Any solutions ?

PS: I wish I could have posted an image but Stack overflow says I can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the duplicates you can use a statement like this as the `Row Source` of the combo box:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Branch_Name] FROM [main table]
```